# Use of python getattr/setattr for current function

Tags: python

Is it possible to use `getattr`/`setattr` to access a variable in a class function?

Example below.  Say I have a class A, that has two methods, `func1` and `func2` both
of which define a variable `count` of a different type.  Is there a way to use
`getattr` in func2 to access the local variable `count`?

In reality, I have quite
a few variables in `func2` (that are also defined differently in `func1`) that I want
to loop through using `getattr` and I'm looking to shorten up my code a bit by using
a loop through the variable names.

```
class A(object):

   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def func1(self):
        count = {"A": 1, "B":2}

   def func2(self):
        count = [1, 2]
        mean = [10, 20]
        for attr in ("count", "mean"):
           xattr = getattr(self, attr)   ! What do I put in here in place of "self"?
           xattr.append(99)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to access `[1, 2]`, not `{"A": 1, "B": 2}`, right?

Comment: Oh lord, don't do this. Just do `count.append(99)` `mean.append(99)`. If you have supermany local variables, go dict instead.

Answer (score 20):

No, `getattr()` and `setattr()` only work with attributes on an object. What you are trying to access are *local variables* instead.

You can use [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) to access a dictionary of local names:

```
for name in ("count", "mean"):
    value = locals()[name]
    value.append(99)
```

but it'd be better just to name the lists directly, there is no need to go through such trouble here:

```
for value in (count, mean):
    value.append(99)
```

Comment: You can actually get the local scope from `sys.modules [__name__]`

Comment: Which requires an import; what exactly is wrong and unhelpful about using the `globals()` dictionary here?

Answer (score 16):

This has been answered before on Stackoverflow... In short:

```
import sys

getattr(sys.modules[__name__], attr)
```

Edit: you can also look up and update the dict returned by `globals()` directly, ex. this is roughly equivalent to the `getattr()` above:

```
globals()[attr]
```